# angular 1.6.2 $resource not working

Tags: angularjs

am learning angular 1.6.2 and am stuck with the $resource getting  Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.2/$injector/unpr?p0=HomeServiceProvider%20%3C-%20HomeService
am not sure what the problem could be please help me

controller.js

```
"user strict";

angular.module('app')
.component('home', {
  restrict: 'E',
  scope: {},
  templateUrl: 'home/home.html',
controller: HomeController

function HomeController(HomeService) {
   var vm = this;
    vm.message = 'Hi from home page';

    vm.users = HomeService.query();
};
```

service.js

```
"use strict";

angular
    .module('app.services', [])
    .factory('HomeService', HomeService);

HomeService.$inject = ['$resource'];

function HomeService($resource) {
    return $resource('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/:user', {user: '@user'}, {
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        }
    });
}
```

app.js

```
"use strict";

angular.module("app", [

  "ui.router",
  "ngResource",
  "app.service"
])
.config([
  "$stateProvider",
  "$urlRouterProvider",
  "$locationProvider",

    function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider ,$locationProvider) {

       $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
       $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
            .state('/home',
            {
                url: "/",
                template: "<home></home>"
            })
            .state('/about',
            {
                url: "/about",
                template: "<about></about>"
            })
            .state('/contact',
            {
                url: "/contact",
                template: "<contact></contact>"
            });
    }
]);
```

Comment: "user strict" in your controller should be "use strict";

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to inject "HomeService" to HomeController?